# Routing in angular with subpages

Tags: angularjs

I have an Angular page where I `ng-repeat` through a projectlist (json).

```
ng-repeat="project in projects"
```

It's structured like this:

```
[{"number":789456,"title":"Coolest project ever","manager":"Darth Vader","image":7,"startdate":"25.1.2013","enddate":"8.7.2015","location":"Deathstar","favorited":"not"}]
```

So, I've made each `ng-repeat` have the following:

```
<a ng-href="#/projects/{{project.number}}"></a>
```

I've set up the route the following way:

```
 .when('/projects', {
        templateUrl: '/views/projects.html',
        controller: 'ProjectController',
        controllerAs: 'pr',
        title: 'Prosjekter'
    })

    .when('/projects/:projectNumber', {
        templateUrl: '/views/projectdetails.html',
        controller: 'ProjectController',
        controllerAs: 'pr',
        title: 'Prosjekt'
    })
```

My controller looks like this:

```
var app = angular.module('app');

app.controller('ProjectController', function($scope, projectList, $mdDialog, $q, $timeout, $routeParams){

  $scope.projectNumber = $routeParams.projectNumber;
  $scope.projects = projectList.query();


  $scope.project = $scope.projects.filter(function(project) {
        return project.number === $routeParams.projectNumber;
    })[0];
```

I get the projectlist from my factory called "projectList".

My problem is, the view loads up correctly, but I have no way of accessing the variables of the project once I'm in this 'child-view' of projects.

I tried using `{{project.number}}`, but it doesn't work. How would I define this in my controller?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your `ProjectController,` you need to use `$routeParams` in order to refer to your `projectNumber` defined in the url.

`{{project.number}}` won't be available until you've defined `$scope.project`. When you need to refer to the project number obtained from the url, use `$routeParams.projectNumber`.

For example, you'd have:

```
app.controller('ProjectController', ['$scope', '$routeParams', function ($scope, $routeParams) {
    var projects = [{...}, ...];
    $scope.project = projects.filter(function(project) {
        return project.number === $routeParams.projectNumber;
    })[0];
}]);
```

Comment: Oh yeah, don't use `{{project.number}}` before you've defined `$scope.project`. to refer to your project number, use `$routeParams.projectNumber`. Does this return `undefined` as well?

Comment: It's still not working. I added the controller code to the post aswell.

Comment: Do you have `ng-route` loaded? It's not part of the main `angular.js`.

Comment: Yes, if I didn't, my routing wouldn't work at all. My problem is just accessing variables inside the subview.

Answer (score 0):

Can you check the type of $routeParams.projectNumber. Is it a string or a number?

Try this in the controller

```
$scope.project = $scope.projects.filter(function(project) {
    return project.number == $routeParams.projectNumber;
})[0];
```

Comment: I already have that code in my controller, ref ccjmne's answer. But it still doesn't work... I've looked at different tutorials but I can't for the hell of me figure out how the view would know which project I clicked on, and give me access to the information from that project. Like, if I click on project number 222103, and get rerouted to #/projects/222103, how would the controller know that I only want to look at project 222103 when I request the {{project.manager}}? I've been looking at different tutorials, and I try to do it the same way but I can't get it to work.

Comment: In your code you have `project.number === $routeParams.projectNumber`. My suggestion is to change it to `project.number == $routeParams.projectNumber`. Use `==` instead of `===`, so type conversion will be performed on the variables. I think $routeParams.projectNumber is a string and project.number is a number.